# Which is better for mobile games, PNG or SVG?

Tags: android, ios, file-format, svg

I want to make several 2D games for mobile platforms, mainly using Qt for iOS, Android, Symbian, MeeGo and whatever supported by Qt.

I've made one game already using PNGs. Now I'm thinking of making a game similar to [Battle Heart](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhZzrcrksY8). What do you think is the best option, PNG files or SVG files or other formats?

Comment: Per Meta, and as mentioned on the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq), "Which technology to use" questions are now deemed off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to port things to reach a maximum audience I would go with SVG because of the fact that they can be easily scaled without a loss of quality. Very useful with for porting to tablets (btw polished table top games on the iPad are doing quite well) and handling the varied screen sizes between various apple and android products.

Note rendering an SVG is going to be slower than a standard file format. However, for a card game you should be fine. Also iOS likes PNGs and PNGs are the only thing that support transparency.

TL:DR

SVG if fast enough and PNG otherwise